# How I study these two sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $a_1=1$ , $a_{n+1}=a_n+(-1)^n \cdot 2^{-n}$ , $b_n=\frac{2 a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n}$
>
> (1) $\{\ {a_n\}}$ converges to $0$ and $\{\ {b_n\}}$ is a cauchy sequence .
>
> (2) $\{\ {a_n\}}$ converges to non-zero number and $\{\ {b_n\}}$ is a cauchy sequence .
>
> (3) $\{\ {a_n\}}$ converges to $0$ and $\{\ {b_n\}}$ is not a cauchy sequence .
>
> (4) $\{\ {a_n\}}$ converges to non-zero number and $\{\ {b_n\}}$ is not a cauchy sequence .

Trial: Here $$\begin{align} a_1 &=1\\ a_2 &=a_1 -\frac{1}{2} =1 -\frac{1}{2} \\ a_3 &= 1 -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} \\ \vdots \\ a_n &= 1 -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} -\cdots +(-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\end{align}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{2}{3}$$ Here I conclude $\{\ {a_n\}}$ converges to non-zero number. Am I right? I know the definition of cauchy sequence but here I am stuck to check. Please help.

Comment: yes, you are right. Since $a_n$ is convergent sequence, so $b_n$ also convergent sequence. And if $x_n$ is convergent sequence, $x_n$ is cauchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have  $b_n=\frac{2 a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n}=2\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1$. For very large values of $n$, since $a_n\to2/3$ we have $a_{n+1}\sim a_n$. So $b_n\to 2-1=1$ so it is Cauchy as well.

Comment: Nice observations, +1

Answer (score 2):

Your argument for the first part is correct $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac23$.

For the second part, $b_n=2\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1$. Since $a_n$ converges to a non-zero limit, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=2\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1=2\cdot1-1=1$. Every convergent sequence is Cauchy, so $b_n$ is Cauchy.